# Focus out event not working as expected in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is the JavaScript I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var left_pos= document.getElementById('login_button').offsetLeft;
        var top_pos= document.getElementById('login_button').offsetTop+5;
        document.getElementById('login_box_pane').style.left=left_pos;
        document.getElementById('login_box_pane').style.top=top_pos;
        $("#login_button").click(function(){$("#login_box_pane").slideToggle(1200);});
            $("#login_box_pane").focusout(function(){$("#login_box_pane").slideUp(1200);
        });
    });
</script>
```

here is the html I am using.

```
   <a id="login_button">login</a> 
   <div id="login_box_pane"  >
     Username: <input type="text"/> 
     Password:<input type="password"/>
   </div>
```

Here is the CSS I am using:

```
#login_box_pane
{
    display:none;
    background-color:#FFBE7D;
    z-index:50;
    width:180px;
    height:130px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

The functionality I want is, whenever the "login" is clicked then there should appear a small box just below that asks for username and other details and it should disappear when ever the "login" is clicked again or anywhere else on the page, that is a focus out.... but it isn't working that way. I even tried mouseout and other events but tough luck. What's wrong with the code?

Is there any other way of achieving this?

Comment: Why are you using plain DOM access if you have jQuery? get if of those four lines using gEBI and use jQuery for it.

Comment: You have spelt 'login_box_pane' incorrectly in your javascript. might just be a typo here, but check your code to make sure

Comment: Actually working for me, http://jsfiddle.net/5q9EA/, or i dont understand what you mean by "it isn't working that way".

Comment: @ThiefMaster didn't get what you meant. I am a starter in web development.

Comment: @sasidhar ThiefMaster mean that you should use "$( '#login_button' )" insead of "document.getElementById('login_button')".

Comment: @Timon.Z toggle is working fine. But when clicked elsewhere or any other button or something else for example i want the login_box_pane to disappear. Thats not working

Comment: @Timon.Z now i get what ThiefMaster meant, ok what is wrong with the functionality now?

Comment: @Tim B James corrected that typing error, but thats not fixing issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
  if(($(e.target).attr('id') == 'login_button')){
    $('#login_box_pane').slideToggle(1200);
  }
  else if(!($(e.target).parents('#login_box_pane').length>0)){
    $('#login_box_pane').slideUp(1200);
  }
});
```

This seems to address my problem correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your answer:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if($(e.target).attr('id') == 'login_button')
       $("#login_box_pane").slideToggle(1200);
    else
       $("#login_box_pane").slideUp(1200);
});
```

**Note:**

1. `e.target` return the on which element the click event happen
2. `$(e.target).attr('id') == 'login_button'` is checking the `id` of clicking element and if the `id` is `login_button`'s, then 'login_box_pane' `slideToggle` happen else it will hide

Here is another code snippet:

```
$("#login_button").click(function(){ 
    $("#login_box_pane").slideToggle(1200).children('input:first').focus();// here I `foucs()` on first input box of the login panel
    return false;
});
$("#login_box_pane").focusout(function(){
    $("#login_box_pane").slideUp(1200);
});
```

Modified version of your code:

```
("#login_button").click(function(){ 
    $("#login_box_pane").slideToggle(1200,function(){
        $('input:first',this).focus();// Here I just make focus() on input that is your `#login_boz_pane`
    });
    return false;
});
$("#login_box_pane").focusout(function(e){
    $(this).slideUp(1200);
});
```

Comment: adcoder the solution is working but why is the focus out event not working..? any idea about that?

Comment: @sasidhar As a jquery beginner I know that `focusout()` needs a `focus()` element. but you have no `focus()` element in your code. If I'm wrong please correct me. I give another code snippet.

Comment: @sasidhar there is no error in your code, but a problem is that you don't make `focus()` in `#login_box_pane`, thats why `focusout()` not working, cos it's not focused. So you need to slightly modify your code to make '#login_box_pane' focused after `slideToggle()`complete and its done.I rewrite that code above.